# Group json array by value

Tags: arrays, vue.js, axios

I'm relatively new to Vue and am trying to organize an API response by country, then state. The following is a sample response from the API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 1"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Lenox",
        "state": "Massachusetts",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 2"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Branson",
        "state": "Missouri",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 3"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Branson",
        "state": "Missouri",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 4"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Tallinn",
        "country": "Estonia",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

I have the code printing successfully on the page, however, I haven't been successful in getting this information organized. The following is the ideal output:

### United States

**Massachusetts**

- Test 1

**Missouri**

- Test 2
- Test 3

### International

**Estonia**

- Test 4

---

The current code I have is:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      properties: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadDestinations: function() {
      axios
        .get("//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/properties?_embed")
        .then(response => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("properties", JSON.stringify(response.data));
          this.properties= response.data;
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("properties")) {
      this.properties= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("properties"));
    } else {
      this.loadDestinations();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 1"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Lenox",
        "state": "Massachusetts",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 2"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Branson",
        "state": "Missouri",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 3"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Branson",
        "state": "Missouri",
        "country": "United States",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Test 4"
    },
    "acf": {
      "address_property": {
        "city": "Tallinn",
        "country": "Estonia",
      }
    }
  }
]

let grouped = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let outerKey = obj.acf.address_property.state === undefined ?  'International' : obj.acf.address_property.country
    let innerKey = outerKey === 'International' ?  obj.acf.address_property.country :  obj.acf.address_property.state
    if (!acc[outerKey]) { acc[outerKey] = {} }
    if (!acc[outerKey][innerKey]) { acc[outerKey][innerKey] = [] }
    acc[outerKey][innerKey].push(obj.title.rendered)
    return acc
  }, {})
  
  
  
console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! Thank you for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like this to reorganize your data before displaying it:

```
function prepareData(data) {
    var countries = {};
    data.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (!(entry.acf.address_property.country in countries)) {
            countries[entry.acf.address_property.country] = {};
        }
        if (!(entry.acf.address_property.city in countries[entry.acf.address_property.country])) {
            countries[entry.acf.address_property.country][entry.acf.address_property.city] = [entry];
        } else {
            countries[entry.acf.address_property.country][entry.acf.address_property.city].push(entry);
        }
    })
    return countries;
}

this.properties = prepareData(response.data);
```